# Multiple regression model

Tags: regression, linear-regression, equation

I have multiple regression model which looks like this:

```
wine.lm <- lm(Alc.vol. ~ pc2+pc1* factor(pc_parametr$color),
              data = pc_parametr)
```

I have to extract the coefficients and translate them into one regression equation for each color (white,red)

```
          Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                         12.6803846  0.2511799 50.4832872 1.104478e-26
pc2                                 -3.7524814  3.5850681 -1.0466974 3.052541e-01
pc1                                 -9.3332435  7.5111530 -1.2425847 2.255503e-01
factor(pc_parameter$color)white      0.4778615  0.2926116  1.6330914 1.149828e-01
pc1:factor(pc_parameter$color)white  6.7281697  8.0999853  0.8306397 4.140399e-01
```

I was trying to do it manually but I am confused.

```
Y = 12.68 + -3.75 * pc2 + -9.33 * pc1 + 0.48 * factor(pc_parametr$color)white + 6.73 * pc1:factor(pc_parametr$color)white + e"
```

Is there a code for the calculation for different colors or manually how is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct equation notation:

[image]

Red color is the reference level and is always included in intercept. In the plot the colors move the regression curve along the y-axis.